# javascript profanity filter on a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a site which filters bad words on an array. Whenever a user types a word on the textbox, an alert box appears if a word from the array was found. I'd like to do the same but instead of using a textbox, I'd like to use a contenteditable div. I'll be needing jquery on this but there seems to be some conflict on my code since the initial code was done in pure js.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/br7TD/

Here's the javascript:

```
var swear_words_arr=new Array("bad","evil","freak");
var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;

function reset_alert_count() {
swear_alert_count=0;
}

function validate_user_text() {
reset_alert_count();
var compare_text=document.form1.user_text.value;

for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
    {
        if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
            {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
    }
}

var alert_text="";  
for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
{
    alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
}

if(swear_alert_count>0) {
    alert("Please refrain from using offensive words"); /* + alert_text */
    document.form1.user_text.select();
    }
else {
    document.form1.submit();
}
}

function select_area() {
document.form1.user_text.select();
}

window.onload=reset_alert_count;
```

I'm pretty much new to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't do this clientside. I can send a POST request directly to your server and bypass all of your JavaScript.

Comment: should I use another method to check/compare the words from the array?

Comment: Do it on your server (with PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, etc.).

Comment: are there any disadvantages if I use jquery?

Comment: Well, not working at all is one.

Comment: I see. So it's highly recommended if I use server side language such as PHP for this?

Comment: Not highly. You just can't do it any other way.

Comment: You should definitely do this at the endpoint of your application. If your application POSTs to a server, do the check on the server. You should also consider using a solution like the [CleanSpeak Profanity Filter](http://www.inversoft.com/features/profanity-filter/) if you want anything beyond simple string matching. CleanSpeak avoids the [scunthorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) problem and many other classic profanity filtering problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="textArea">
    <span id="myInput" contenteditable="true">kfjdkfj</span>
</div>
```

And

```
var swear_words_arr=new Array("bad","evil","freak");
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + swear_words_arr.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i' );

function validate_user_text() {
    var text = $('#myInput').text();

    if(regex.test(text)) {
        alert("Please refrain from using offensive words"); /* + alert_text */
        $('#myInput').focus();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rMJxR/3/)

a more jQuery like solution can be [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rMJxR/4/)

Comment: oh, I see that you used regex for that. I think I've kind of got it already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @false-hero you still need to do this validation in the server side, else anybody who has some basic knowledge about web application can override this

Comment: Does that mean that it is highly preferred if instead of using javascript, I should use PHP?

Comment: @false-hero you need to use both, since javascript validation will give normal users a faster response and a better user experience, but for those who are trying to be smart you need to have server side validation also. In web development any validation done on the client side using a script has to be retested again in the server

Comment: I see. I'll be working with a PHP developer for this project so hopefully it would work well. Thanks again for the helpful response!

Comment: You will run into regex issues depending on the size of your array.

Comment: Do you know how to make a separate file with a list of banned words, then parse the file's contents into an array instead of hardcoding it all in?